# Android Studio Render problem failed to find style

Tags: android-studio

Acabo de empezar con android studio apenas ayer, me esta dando muchos errores, adb.exe missing, gradle error, haxm, en fin ya pude solucionar esos pero ahora me esta dando estos errores:

> Render problem failed to find style

y

> Couldn't resolve resource.

Me tope con que podía cambiar `compileSdkVersion 27`
`targetSdkVersion 27` pero no funcionó. No se si se me paso instalar algo, como digo apenas lo instale ayer. Tengo win 7 y Android Studio 3.1.4[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Bueno despues de leer varios articulos lo resolvi de esta manera. Lo dejo aqui por si alguien se topa con estos errores.

Ve a file > settings > Android SDK, marca la casilla que dice show package details, instala Android 8.1 SDK platform 27 y Sources for Andorid 27, dale ok. despues de que termine de actualizarse, en el panel de la derecha dale doble click a build.gradle module app y cambia los siguientes valores:
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
Al parecer la version 28 esta dando problemas a algunos de nosotros, por que? no lo se, pero asi fue como lo resolvi, asi que si estan instalando y usando android studio por primera vez y no tienen a nadie quien los guie con la instalacion pues asi lo pueden resolver.